# How to sort a matrix based on the number of occurrences of a particular value in a corresponding column without using for loops?

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have a matrix, whose first column contains user IDs, and the second column contains 1s and 0s. I need to find out the top 10 user IDs with the most number of 1s. That is, if the input matrix is the following,

```
27 0
36 0
36 1
36 0
36 0
27 0
27 0
36 1
27 0
27 0
27 0
27 0
27 1
36 0
```

I want the output to be the following:

```
36 2
27 1
```

That is, even though `27` occurs 8 times and `36` occurs only 6 times, `36` should come on top of `27` because it has more number of `1` values in the original matrix. How do I do this without using a for loop, because for loop takes a lot of time, and the matrix is actually a pretty big one, with lots of unique user IDs.

Comment: Which language are you using and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @albert MATLAB. I used the `matlab` tag when posting the question.

Comment: What does the number 2 mean here?

Comment: @choroba The frequency of occurrence. `36` has the value `1` 2 times, `27` has the value `1` 1 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That problem setup seems perfect for solving with [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) & [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) -

```
%// Select rows with col-2 as 1s & find unique col-1 elements and IDs 
[unq_sA1,~,id] = unique(A(A(:,2)==1,1))

%// Get counts of such unique rows
counts = accumarray(id(:),1)

%// Get argsort for the counts to index into unique rows and the counts
[~,sort_idx] = sort(counts,'descend')
out = [unq_sA1(sort_idx) counts(sort_idx)]
```

Comment: Very nice solution. Probably also clearly faster than my solution.

Comment: @hbaderts Thanks! Yeah `arrayfun` aren't fun for performance AFAIK :)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm accepting your solution as the answer because it solved the problem in 1 second. My naive method involving 2 for loops, as I would have done in C, took more than 12 hours, and the other gentleman's answer above took 2 hours to do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can find all user IDs with the [`unique`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function, which returns all unique values in an array:

```
ids = unique(inp(:,1));
```

The number of ones for an id can calculated by

```
sum( inp(inp(:,1)==ID,2) )
```

which uses some [matrix indexing](http://mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to find all rows where the first entry is the selected user id `ID`, and sums up the second entries of those rows.

To do these sums in a vectorized fashion, you can e.g. use the [`arrayfun`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) function, which applies a function to each element of the supplied array. The function you'll want to call is the sum introduced above, and you want to apply it to all unique IDs. This is done by

```
arrayfun(@(x)sum(inp(inp(:,1)==x,2)),ids)

ans = 
    1
    2
```

Comment: When I try your code, I get the following error: `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.` Plus, its not very clear how to use your code. So I ran the `arrayfun` inside a for loop, `for x=1:size(ids(:,1),1)`. Even then the error persists.

Comment: No need for a loop: `arrayfun` applies the function to each value in `ids`. Just run the first line `ids = ...` (and maybe check if it is correct), and then call the line `arrayfun(...)`.

Comment: It works, but when I apply it on my actually matrix, it doesn't cut the time. With the 2 for loops, it took me more than 12 hours to do the job. And with your solution, its already been more than an hour. I hope it won't take more than 10 hours, because then its performance would be equivalent to the 2 for loops.

Comment: Do you have a Parallel Computing Toolbox license? You can probably speed it up by running it on a GPU. This however depends on the array, your GPU and so on, so you'll probably have to try to find out.

Comment: I checked in the `Apps` section; there's no `Parallel Computing` toolbox there. But I tried out the `parfor` loop, and I found that it is actually slower than the normal `for` loop. In fact, as the number of CPUs increases, the time taken increases!